# building an array based on percentage

Tags: php

I would like to "for loop" through a large number and build an array of items that is x% one way and x% another.

For the sake of exmaple: 
I want to generate an array of fake customer records.

The idea is that at the end of the loop, I will have an array that contains 20% users that only contain a customer id and 80% users that contain first name, last name and known details. The generation of the details isn’t important, it’s the percentage that is split in the loop that is.

So far this is what I was working with:

```
    $percentage = $percent_known / 100;
    $percnum = $this->number_of_records * $percentage;
    $iterat = $this->number_of_records / $percnum;

    for ($i=0; $i < $this->number_of_records; $i++) { 
        if ($i % $iterat == 0) {
            //add known records
        }
        else {
            //just add a customer id
        }
    }
```

when put 80 as the value of $percent_known I get an iterat of 1.25 and all my records are known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it to fill in all of the known ones ( by filling in up to `$percnum`) and then add the unknown ones.  If you want them to be random, then just use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) at the end to mix the results together...

```
$percentage = $percent_known / 100;
$percnum = $this->number_of_records * $percentage;

$customers = [];
for ($i=0; $i < $this->number_of_records; $i++) {
    if ($i < $percnum) {
        //add known records
    }
    else {
        //just add a customer id
    }
}
shuffle($customers);
```

If the values are the same - you can always generate a batch using [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) rather than using a loop and merge the two formats and again shuffle the results.